Split TOC into two columns with different contents
I would like to make an outline frame such that the frame is seperated into two columns.
On the left, it would have the sections with show/shaded option.
On the right, it would have the subsections of the current section.
I don't know where in the sty I need to change things.
Ideally, it would look like this

Please add a short, but compilable test file which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a document environment.

\documentclass{beamer}

\AtBeginSection[]{
  \begin{frame}
  \begin{columns}
  \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
  \tableofcontents[
    currentsection,
    subsectionstyle=hide/hide/hide
  ]
  \end{column}
  \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
  \setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{}
  \tableofcontents[%
    currentsection,
    sectionstyle=show/hide,
    subsectionstyle=show/show/hide
    ]
  \end{column}
  \end{columns}
  \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}


\section{sec}
\subsection{sub}
\subsection{subb}
\begin{frame}
  abc
\end{frame}

\section{secc}
\subsection{subbb}
\subsection{subbbb}
\begin{frame}
  abc
\end{frame}

\end{document}


